# How to replace a string in a variable with another string in a file using shell script

Tags: shell, sed, replace

I want to replace a string with another in shell execustion jenkins.

This works:

```
sed -i 's/\/opt\/Project\/workspace\/'${PRODUCT}'\/common\/ci_build_Type-'${SUB_PRODUCT}'/\/home\/Projects\/XXX\/'${PRODUCT}'\/common\/ci_build_polyspace_Type-'${SUB_PRODUCT}'/g' polyspaceFiles_${SUB_PRODUCT}_tmp.opts;
```

But I want to have it like this

```
#!/bin/sh

WORKSPACE="/opt/Project/jenkins/XX/XX/XX/XX/XXX-XXX"
echo $WORKSPACE
PRODUCT="MyProject"
SUB_PRODUCT="MySubProject"
sed -i 's/'$WORKSPACE'/\/home\/Projects\/XXX\/'$PRODUCT'\/common\/XXX-'$SUB_PRODUCT'/g' polyspaceFiles_$SUB_PRODUCT_tmp.opts;
```

But it doesn't work.

How can I do That?

Thanks

Comment: `$WORKSPACE` contains `/` characters. So you need to use a different character for the delimiters in the `s` command.

Comment: would you please write me how to do that? I am not really an expert with REGEX.

Comment: Change `s/.../.../` to `s|...|...|` where `|` is a character that won't appear in any of the variables.

Comment: This works, Thanks, I just want to know if I want to substitute one string with a dot how it works? I am doing sed -i 's|'$WORKSPACE'|.|g' myfile   but it doesn't work

Comment: That should work. dot has no special meaning in the replacement.

Comment: Perfect solution. would you please write the answer so I accept it as the working solution? Thanks

Comment: There are already a couple of similar answers.

Comment: What are `$PASE_PRODUCT` and `$PASE_SUB_PRODUCT_tmp`?

Comment: If the variable is just `$PASE_SUB_PRODUCT`, you need to separate it from `_tmp`.  Use `polyspaceFiles_${PASE_SUB_PRODUCT}_tmp.opts`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default delimiter of `sed` clashes with the same character's present in your `WORKPLACE`. As mentioned in the comments, changing the delimiter to a character not present in any of your input or escaping the slashes would work for that issue.

However, you also have a single quoting issue. Not only would you get an error, the variables will not expand.

This `sed` should work

```
$ sed -i.bak s"|$WORKSPACE|/home/Projects/XXX/$PASE_PRODUCT/common/XXX-$SUB_PRODUCT|" polyspaceFiles_"$PASE_SUB_PRODUCT"_tmp.opts
```

Comment: The single quotes aren't around the variables in their code. So it should work as long as the variable doesn't contain spaces.

Answer (score 0):

You can use characters other than `/` as delimiter for `sed`'s `s`ubstitution command.
That way you don't have to escape all the slashes in your paths to avoid syntax breakage.

E.g. you could use `~` as demonstrated below, if you're sure it won't be in any of your paths variables.
(You can also use any of `#`, `%`, `*`, `+`, `|`, etc. as substitution delimiter. Whatever fits your need. Just make sure all three delimiters used in the `s` command are the same.)

```
sed -i 's~'"$WORKSPACE"'~/home/Projects/XXX/'"$PASE_PRODUCT"'/common/XXX-'"$SUB_PRODUCT"'~g' "polyspaceFiles_$PASE_SUB_PRODUCT_tmp.opts";
```